# load scene in json using sceneLoader

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, three.js

i am trying to load a scene that i select from my MONGODB and when my client get it i want to load the scene using SceneLoader and show it but it wont work and always says :

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

this is my code :

```
        function showscene(sceanInJson)
        {
            var sceneLoader = new THREE.SceneLoader();
            var loadScene = new THREE.Scene();

            sceneLoader.parse(JSON.parse(sceanInJson), function (e) {
                loadScene = e.scene;
            }, '.');

            render(loadScene);
        }
```

the scean is in json that i load from the DB, and now i want to show it here, the error is in the `sceneLoader.parse` line

any help will be grate,
thanks

Comment: What line of code is failing? Is THREE.js included on your web page?

Comment: yes it is include, the line that failing is sceneLoader.parse(JSON.parse(sceanInJson), function (e) {
                loadScene = e.scene;
            }, '.'); there i have the error above

Comment: What is undefined then? Is `sceneLoader` set to a value? `parse`?

Comment: all is define, parse its a method, can someone help ?

Comment: When you step through with the debugger, what isn't defined? Set a breakpoint on the line with `parse`, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when an object-type in the json does not have a corresponding class loaded. Perhaps because you forgot to include the file for that type of object? Or because the classname was saved incorrectly.

Also, it would be helpful if you made the actual JSON available.

To understand the error, this is what is (probably) happening:

```
new THREE[ "SomeClassThatDoesntExist" ]();
```